¿ Como crear login con certficado digital en mi web? reactjs + javascript
El objetivo es permitir que los usuarios se autentiquen en la web utilizando un certificado digital almacenado en su navegador Aquí algunos detalles adicionales del entorno de desarrollo:
Framework: React
Lenguaje: JavaScript
IDE: Visual Studio Code Versión: 1.86.1
Sistema operativo: macOS.
Sabeis como podria hacerlo ?

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
